# Reject entries based on negative regex pattern

Tags: ruby, regex

I want a regex that catches this entry

```
/zones/sector_1+2/zone_1+2.json
```

but not this one

```
/zones/sector_1+2/zone_1+2.dae.json
```

The difference lies in `.dae`.

The initial regex was

```
/Zones\/(?<sector>.*)\/(?<zone>.*)\.(?<extension>json)/i
```

And this catches both entries as expected. I tried something like this

```
/Zones\/(?<sector>.*)\/(?<zone>.*)(\.?)(?!dae)(\.?)(?<extension>json)/i
```

and this one catches both entries as well. In fact this works as expected

```
/Zones\/(?<sector>.*)\/zone_1\+2(\.?)(?!dae)(\.?)(?<extension>json)/i
```

but I have no idea what `(?<zone>.*)` can be. Any ideas?

Comment: Something simple like this won't work? `/zones\/(\w+\+\d+)/(\w+\+\d).json`

Comment: Is catching both entries expected or not?

Comment: Try [`/Zones\/(?<sector>[^\/]*)\/(?![^\/]*\.dae\.json)(?<zone>[^\/]*)\.(?<extension>json)/`](https://regex101.com/r/oT2uW9/1)

Comment: Why `(?<extension>json)` rather than just `json`?

Comment: As @mudasobwa answer `Negative lookbehind can NOT contain multipliers (+/*)` so your answers aren't working. @cary-swoveland I don't understand the purpose of your question, but the answer is for later abstraction and factorisation in my code...

Comment: @sawa Thanks to make me question more understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that

```
"/zones/sector_1+2/zone_1+2.json"
```

is a match but

```
"/zones/sector_1+2/zone_1+2.dae.json"
```

is not. That does not, however, imply the rules for what constitutes a match. For example, is

```
"/zones/sector_1+2/zone_1+2.dog.json"
```

a match, and if so, is the group named `zone` to be `"zone_1+2.dog"`? I have made the assumption that the `zone` group *cannot* contain a period. In that case you can write the following:

```
r = /
    \A    # match beginning of string
    \/    # match forward slash
    zones # match string
    \/     # match forward slash
    (?<sector>[^\/]+) # Match any chars other than forward slash in group 'sector'
    \/     # match forward slash
    (?<zone>[^.]+)   # Match any chars other than period in group 'zone'
    \.json # match a period followed by a string
    \z     # match the end of the string
    /ix    # case-independent (i) and extended/free-spacing regex definition  (x) modes

str = "/zones/sector_1+2/zone_1+2.json" 
m = str.match(r)
  #=> #<MatchData "/zones/sector_1+2/zone_1+2.json" sector:"sector_1+2" zone:"zone_1+2"> 
m[:sector]
  #=> "sector_1+2" 
m[:zone]
  #=> "zone_1+2" 

str = "/zones/sector_1+2/zone_1+2.dae.json"
m = str.match(r)
  #=> nil
```

There is no need for a capture group

```
(?<extension>json)
```

as "json" is a literal (unlike, for example, `(?<sector>.*)`, where the value captured is determined at run-time). That is, if this capture group were included, we would *always* obtain

```
m[:extension]
  #=> "json"
```

Comment: This is definitely the best answer! Thanks for documented well the regex.

Answer (score 2):

```
/(^\/zones\/.*\/.*\.dae\.json)|(^\/zones\/.*\/.*\.json)$/gm
```

I created this using regexr (find here http://regexr.com/3cthi)

It captures into two groups, the first matching `.dae.json`, the second just `.json`.  The second capture group should contain all the files you want, while the first will contain the ones you don't.  However I haven't tested performance so it may be awful.

It requires the global and multiline tags.

Comment: Interesting but I really want to exclude here, btw for what `gm` stand for?

Answer (score 1):

[Negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) can not contain multipliers (`+`/`*`), but in case of zones the below seems to suffice:

```
/(?<!\.\w|\.\w\w|\.\w\w\w|\.\w\w\w\w)\.json\Z/
```

It will accept everything, ending with `.json`, but having no `.\w{,4}` before it. The leading part might be added accordingly.

Comment: Ok Thanks I guess is what I missed and your answer is what I need `Zones\/(?<sector>.*)\/(?<zone>.*)(?<!\.\w\w\w)\.(?<extension>json)`

Comment: Mudsie, can you use `\K` rather than a negative lookbehind?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I am not sure I understand how `\K` might be used here.